# Does a batch command exist for sheet.setColumnWidth(columnPosition, width)?

Tags: google-apps-script

Instead of using sheet.setColumnWidth(columnPosition, width) several times, I would like to use a single command for more than one column.

Comment: Hehe, you should have just answered it :) no @Serge ?

Answer (score 0):

Long answer: No, such method does not exist.

You can open an enhancement request for this on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: :-)  I love it Henrique.